# How to declare arrays which are functions argument, if their size is to be determined by the user input at the start of program

Tags: c++

For my "basics of programming" project i was ordered to make a "memory game". 2 players in their respective turns choose which cards to reveal on a "m x n" sized board. "m" and "n" are to be chosen at the start of each game. My question is, how can I create an array of structures used to display the board a the moment of user's input. So far I just used a const int to create an array of a maximum size, however more than 95% of the arrays indexes are empty using this method. Is there a way to create the array right after user's input while also having those functions defined and declared with an array of structures that's the size of the input? Here's my code so far:

```
const int MAX_M = 1000;
const int MAX_N = 1000;
Karta Plansza2[MAX_M][MAX_N];

void SprawdzanieParzystosci(int& m, int& n);
void RozmiaryTablicy(int& m, int& n);
void generuj(int m, int n, Karta Plansza[MAX_M][MAX_N]);
void WyswietleniePlanszy(int m, int n, Karta Plansza[MAX_M][MAX_N]);

void generuj(int m, int n, Karta Plansza[][MAX_N])
{

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    char A;
    int B;
    int C;
    int D;
    int k = 0;
    int w1, w2, k1, k2;
                                    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Plansza[i][j].WartoscKarty = 0;
        }
        

    while (k < (m*n))
    {
            A = char(rand() % 10 + 65);
            B = (rand() % 10);
            C = (rand() % 10);
            D = ((rand() % 2000000) + 1);
            do{
                w1 = rand() % m;
                k1 = rand() % n;
            }while(Plansza[w1][k1].WartoscKarty != 0);
            Plansza[w1][k1].ZnakPierwszy = A;
            Plansza[w1][k1].LiczbaPierwsza = B;
            Plansza[w1][k1].LiczbaDruga = C;
            Plansza[w1][k1].WartoscKarty = D;
            k++;
            do{
                w2 = rand() % m;
                k2 = rand() % n;
            } while (Plansza[w2][k2].WartoscKarty != 0);
            Plansza[w2][k2].ZnakPierwszy = A;
            Plansza[w2][k2].LiczbaPierwsza = B;
            Plansza[w2][k2].LiczbaDruga = C;
            Plansza[w2][k2].WartoscKarty = D;
            k++;
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void WyswietleniePlanszy(int m, int n, Karta Plansza[MAX_M][MAX_N])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << "***" << setw(5);
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << "*" << Plansza[i][j].ZnakPierwszy << "*" << "  ";
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << "*" << Plansza[i][j].LiczbaPierwsza << "*" << "  ";
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << "*" << Plansza[i][j].LiczbaDruga << "*" << "  ";
        cout << "\n";
        //  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        //  cout << wzor[i][j].num4 << "  ";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << "***" << setw(5);
        cout << "\n";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void RozmiaryTablicy(int& m, int& n)
{
    cout << "Podaj rozmiar m tablicy: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Podaj rozmiar n tablicy: ";
    cin >> n;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void SprawdzanieParzystosci(int& m, int& n)
{
    while ((m * n) % 2 != 0 || (m <= 0) || (n <= 0)) {
        RozmiaryTablicy(m, n);
        if((m * n) % 2 != 0 || (m <= 0) || (n <= 0)) cout << "Zle dane. Prosze podac dane jeszcze raz" << endl;    
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    int m =1;
    int n =1;
    SprawdzanieParzystosci(m, n);
    generuj(m,n,Plansza2);
    WyswietleniePlanszy(m,n,Plansza2);

    cout << m << endl;
    cout << n << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For example, If the user inputs m = 5 an n = 6 it would create an Plansza[5][6] array instead of a Plansza[1000][1000] array

Comment: That's impossible in C++. Use a `vector` instead.

Comment: Hello, I was forbidden to use nonstandard libraries and I can't use <vector> in this project, I was thinking maybe there was a way with dynamic arrays but i can't find a solution to this problem anywhere

Comment: if you are not allowed to use `std::vector` write your own. The hardest part is getting memory mangment right and this you have to do anyhow. The rest is bells and whistles

Comment: @KrzysiekDymanowski `std::vector` is a standard library though, so it shouldn't be any problem. I'd be more surprised that you're allowed to use `system("pause");`.

Comment: But if you don't want to use a vector, then you can just allocate memory the good old-fashioned way with [`new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/) or `malloc`. However, then you'll have to remember to free it and also to reallocate when you want to resize the array. You'd also have to keep track of the size of the array (it isn't done automatically) and make sure you don't step outside of its boundaries.

Comment: Some general tips; most people don't know Polish. Just write your code in English from the start, because 1) Practiacally all work places requires it. 2) Non-Polish people (like us) will understand the code better and help you easier. 3) C++ is already in English, so keep it consistent. Also, the `/` comments you use to separate things are a bit noisy/distracting. I'd suggest to just use newlines instead.

Comment: Thanks Ted, the problem is I started programming 2 months ago and I'm not really sure how i could implement dynamic arrays into my code. Do i just replace every instance of Board (Plansza) with *Board? and then every Board[i][j].NumberOne = 16 with Board[i][j]->NumberOne  = 16 ?

Comment: it is possible to use `std::vector` correctly after 2 months, but after 20 years you can still make mistakes with dynamic arrays managed by raw pointers. If you are not allowed to use `std::vector` thats just sad

Comment: *I was forbidden to use nonstandard libraries and I can't use <vector> in this project,* -- So the goal is to not create a memory game, it is to try and write dynamic arrays.  This is why more and more programmers are dropping C++ and learning Java, JavaScript, Python, or some other language.  It's because of silly restrictions like "you can't use vector".  Those other languages, the new programmer is actually writing the game code, not fooling around with implementing dynamic arrays, linked lists, string classes, etc.

Comment: Hey Paul. No, the goal isnt to use dynamic arrays, the goal is to make a functional game, my other classmates had stuff like tic tac toe, sudoku, domino and games like that to make, mine was just randomly assigned to be a memory game

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack of a board, remark the nice `board[row][column]` notation and the returned reference to the field. C++17 (might work in C++14)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

using DaType = char;
class Board {
  int rows = 0;
  int cols = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<DaType[]> board; // RAII
public:
  class Row {
    DaType *board;
  public:
    Row(DaType *row) : board(row) {}
    DaType& operator[](int col) { return board[col]; }
  };
  Board(int row, int col) : rows(row), cols(col), board(std::make_unique<DaType[]>(row*col)) { memset(board.get(), '.', rows*cols); }
  Row operator[](int row) { return Row(board.get()+row*cols); }
};


int main() {
  const int sx = 6, sy = 10;
  Board board(sx,sy);
  board[3][5] = 'x';
  for (int i = 0; i < sx; ++i ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sy; ++j )
      std::cout << board[i][j];
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Ps. it seemed simpler last time I did this ...

Update thanks to IlCapitano

```
class Board {
  int rows = 0;
  int cols = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<DaType[]> board; // RAII
public:
  Board(int row, int col) : rows(row), cols(col), board(std::make_unique<DaType[]>(row*col)) { memset(board.get(), '.', rows*cols); }
  DaType *operator[](int row) { return board.get()+row*cols; }
};
```

Comment: In the `operator[]` of `Board` you could just return the pointer calculated with `board.get() + row*cols` instead of using a proxy class.  The behaviour would be the same, but the class itself is much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to solve this would be to just use `std::vector`, since the size of arrays in arguments, stackallocations, etc. has to be known at compile-time.

The easiest option without using vector would be to declare `Plansza2` as a `Karta*` and allocate the memory dynamically after `SprawdzanieParzystosci` using `Plansza2 = new Karta[m*n];` (Don't forget to call `delete[](Plansza2);` before ending your program). If you do this you can access the cells with `Plansza2[y * m + x]` (assuming `m` is width and `n` is height). The advantage of mapping the 2-dimensional array to a 1 dimensional array by placing all rows after one another is that you only need one allocation and one deletion, and furthermore it improves cache-friendliness.

A cleaner way to solve this (removing the possibility for a memory leak if something throws an exception or you forget to call `delete`) would be to create your own class for 2-dimensional arrays, that would call `new[]` in the constructor and `delete[]` in the destructor. If you do that you could define `Karta& operator()(int x, int y);` and `const Karta& operator()(int x, int y) const;` to return the appropriate cell, allowing you to access a cell with `dynamicMap(x, y)`. `operator[]` can only take one argument and is therefor more complicated to use to access a 2-dimensional array (you can for example take an std::pair as the argument or return a proxy-class that also has operator[] defined). However if you write your own destructor, you need to take care of the copy-(always) and move-(c++11 onwards) constructors and assignment operators, since the default instantiations would lead to your destructor trying to delete the same pointer multiple times. An example for a move-assignment operator is:

```
    DynamicMap& DynamicMap::operator=( DynamicMap&& map ){
        if(this == &map)
            return *this;  //Don't do anything if both maps are the same map
        dataPointer = map.dataPointer;  //Copy the pointer to "this"
        map.dataPointer = nullptr;  //Assign nullptr to map.dataPointer because delete[] does nothing if called with null as an argument
        //You can move other members in the above fashion, using std::move for types more complex than a pointer or integral, but be careful to leave map in a valid, but empty state, so that you do not try to free the same resource twice.
        return *this;
    }
```

The move constructor doesn't require the if-clause at the start, but is otherwise identical and the copy-constructor/assignment operator should probably declared as `= delete;` since it will probably be a bug if you copy your map. If you do need to define the copy operations, do not copy the pointer but instead create a new array and copy the contents.

Comment: Hi. thank you very much for your answer, I tried making it the way you described it in the second paragraph, however im not quite sure how would i have to rewrite my `generuj` function then in order for it to work again. I actually asked around and for such a small program(also im not studying computer science but robotics, CS students have to be much more precise in their projects) I can just `#define MAX_M  1000` and then declare and define every Plansza as `Plansza[MAX_M][MAX_M]`

Comment: The declaration of the function would have to be `void generuj(int m, int n, Karta Plansza*)` and every occurrence of an arrayaccess would have to be replaced with the `x + y * m` thing, for example `Plansza[i + j * m].WartoscKarty = 0;`.